# Truecrypt - I lost my booloader and recovery drive but know my password.. any help?

Tags: bootloader, truecrypt, restore

So earlier today a not-so-thought-out install of Ubuntu overwrote my MBR and destroyed my TrueCrypt bootloader. On checking, it turns out that my rescue disk is only 2mb and doesn't contain any visible files inside it!

I do know my password.. any ideas on how I could restore the Truecrypt Bootloader or create a new Rescue Disk?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried booting from the rescue disk anyway?
The files on the disk could be hidden.

The rescue disk is a copy of the MBR so I don't see why it should have a large file size - although I may be wrong.

[Check this.](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=rescue-disk)

Comment: There are no actual files on the rescue disc - just the TrueCrypt bootloader.